# Unable to docker run

Tags: docker, osrm, docker-run

I am trying to setup an image of the osrm-backend on my docker. I am unable to run docker using the below commands (as mentioned in [wiki](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Docker-Recipes))

```
docker run -t -v ${pwd}/data osrm/osrm-backend:v5.18.0 osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/denmark-latest.osm.pbf
docker run -t -v ${pwd}:/data osrm/osrm-backend:v5.18.0 osrm-contract /data/denmark-latest.osrm
docker run -t -i -p 5000:5000 -v ${pwd}/data osrm/osrm-backend:v5.18.0 osrm-routed /data/denmark-latest.osrm
```

I have already fetched the corresponding map using both wget and Invoke-WebRequest. Every time I run the first command from the above, it gives the error...

> [error] Input file /data/denmark-latest.osm.pbf not found!

I have tried placing the downloaded maps in the corresponding location as well. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

I am using PowerShell on Windows 10

Comment: The wiki has `-v $(pwd):/data` (with a colon) in all three `docker run` commands.  Did you do that too?  (`-v $(pwd)/data` without a colon would be syntactically valid but mean something very different.)

Comment: I did that too. I had to change the paranthesis to curly brackets to make it compatible with windows and powershell. I thought, I had to remove the colon after that, I tried that again now, but the same issue

Comment: i have the exact same issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: no, unfortunately, no one gave the answer and I had to move on to another high priority project... :)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that docker was not able to access the C drive, even though the sharing was turned on in docker settings. After wasting lots of time, I turned off the sharing of C drive, and then turned it back on. After that when I mounted some folder to docker, it was able to see the files.

[Docker share drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1hn7.png)